# Approximation by using Taylor Polynomials - why?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

Could anyone tell me why would I want to approximate a function $f$ by using its Taylor expansion (is it the same as saying approximation by Taylor polynomials?), if I have the exact formula of the function $f$?

Why approximate a function if I have its formula? What's wrong with having the formula for $f$ that anyone would want to approximate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many situations where you want linear or quadratic approximations of some complicated function at a point (i.e. first or second degree Taylor expansion).

- Linear or quadratic functions are easy to work with.
- Linear or quadratic approximations may be all that's needed.

These situations come up all over the place in wildly different contexts:

1. Numerical optimization: [many algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming) repeatedly (i) build a quadratic approximation of the function at a point and (ii) take a step towards the minimum based on that quadratic model. Repeat till convergence is reached.
2. Linear or low order polynomial approximations of non-linear dynamics. This is all over the place in economic modeling and I imagine other types of modeling as well.
3. Asymptotic behavior. If you zoom in enough, smooth functions will look linear. You can model behavior in a local neighborhood with a linear approximation. (This is basic idea behind the [Delta Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) in statistics).
4. Approximate various constants, etc... that don't have analytic solutions by using taylor expand.

List goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

Reason 1: Let's say you need to program a computer to calculate values of $\log x$. (That is, you are the first person to program $\log$.) You might want to use a Taylor expansion.

Reason 2: You need to calculate $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin^2 t}{e^t - 1 - t}$.

Reason 3: You are studying a parametric curve $(f(t),g(t))$ near $t = a$. The geometric properties of the curve (tangents, half-tangents, cusps, etc.) will be determined by the Taylor expansions of $f$ and $g$ at $a$.

Reason 4: You want an approximate value of the integral of the function over an interval, and no explicit antiderivative can be found.

Answer (score 0):

How do you compute $\sin(x)$ for small $x$? And how *small* it should be? This can be done easily using Taylor approximation. We know that $\sin(x)=x+O(x^3)$, so you can just take $\sin(x) = x$ in case you are OK with third-order error. More practical estimates on the remainder [are known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder), so that you can compute the function with *known bounds for the error*.

How do you compute the limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x-1}$? Or, better, how can you predict the behavior of the function under limit as $x$ goes to infinity? Use Taylor approximation! 
$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1}=x \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}\right) \approx x \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^2}+\frac{1}{16x^4}\right) - \left(1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^2}-\frac{1}{16x^4}\right)\right)=x\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{8x^4}\right)=1+\frac{1}{8x^3}$$

So, the limit is clearly 1, and the function behaves as $1+\frac{1}{8x^3}$. A lot of information from a single theorem!

Taylor approximation gives you the function's *local behavoir* in terms of functions that we fully understand (that is, polynomials), which is an extremely powerful technique in analysis.